# Windows mobile without store

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine

I work in unity, but i never develop for windows tablet, i need to launch an app build in unity on windows tablet, is a custom app, is possibile build in unity an app and install manually into tablet windows without pass from store?

thank you

Comment: Unless its been locked down to only use the store, you should be able to install any windows app on it

Answer (score 0):

If tablet SO is Windows and not Windows Mobile, you can build your proyect with PC build (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html) and go on.